# Does C# 3.0 support the concept of partial properties?

Tags: c#, serialization, properties, partial

I am using Linq to sql concept to manipulate my data from asp.net mvc application to sql server.
In the middle of flow, I need to serialize the objects, but for some reason LINQ doesn't support circular class associations.

I used [Scriptingnore] attribute to those properties which are not able to serialize. This works fine.

But I want to avoid to changing the designer.cs file generated by the framework again and again. So I was just thinking about how if I can create partial class of those classes and make partial those properties too in these partial classes. That way I would not need to change the designer .cs file. So is there any such concept, so that I can avoid adding the attribute to the property in the designer.cs class? That way I would get relief from making the changes every time I drag the tables on .dbml file.

( it needs me because slide change in db or that class's name table need to recreate that class or designer class totally)

Comment: I suggest you to use POCO template or any Entity template for generating data classes because it use T4 to generate all source code. You can add some logic to detect circular class associations and write your ignore serialization attribute before it render property name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no such feature as partial properties.

I'm not sure the best approach to use for this, to be honest... other than potentially automating the process of updating the designer file, or changing the way you do serialization.

Comment: are you sure John ? if yes then can we say this is limitation of .net framework 3.5?

Comment: @Lalit: I'm absolutely sure that there's no such thing as partial properties - and even the nearest equivalent, partial methods, don't really allow you do to this. It's not a limitation of the framework - the language *could* allow something like this, although I suspect it's a sufficiently rare situation that it's unlikely to come in a future version.

Comment: ok, i agree with you.but can you suggest me some way to sort out this situation in my application ?

Comment: @Lalit: Well, I've suggested either automating the update (process the source file) or changing your serialization strategy. Unfortunately I don't have enough experience of JavaScript serialization to make concrete suggestions about alternatives.

Comment: @ Tuomas Hietanen : how can we achieve this by interfaces ?

Comment: Though i have accepted , but i expect here, for how can we achieve that by interface.